# How to stop auto sliding of react-bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

***By installing "npm i react-bootstrap". I added Below code in html. I have used interval="false" but it was not working. In bootstrap it working but not working in react "react-bootstrap". Please help me out***

```
function ControlledCarousel() {
   const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    setIndex(selectedIndex);
  };*strong text*

  return (
    <Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect}>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
          alt="First slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"
          alt="Second slide"
        />

        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>Second slide label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a"
          alt="Third slide"
        />

        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          <p>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
          </p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using React-Bootstrap version 1 I had to set `interval={null}` as with 0 it was sliding non-stop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `interval={0}` to `Carousel`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `interval` as 0. This can be done via interval prop, by setting as below. The default value is `'5000'`

```
<Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect} interval={0}>
```